# How to drag & drop only one file on form window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have one windows application in c#, i want to add drag & drop facility in this application, after adding this facility it takes multiple files, so I want to take only one file at a time, how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I am new in c# language, so i don't know any way

Comment: have you added anything? "after adding this facility" means you have done drag and drop and want to limit it to one file only?

Comment: yes, I want it with one file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read the code below and try applying it to your situation

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.AllowDrop = true;
    this.DragEnter += Form1_DragEnter;
    this.DragDrop += Form1_DragDrop;
}

void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    if (files.Length == 1)
    {
        // do what you want
    }
    else
    {
        // show error
    }
}
```